# Issue on the Unity Learn Platform (Junior Programmer Lesson 1-4)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I was working in the Unity Learn program, and the first mission is where we make a vehicle drive down the road and avoid obstacles. However, when I got to implementing turning in lesson 1-4, it wouldn't adjust the turnSpeed with the horizontalInput. The horizontalInput adjusts in the inspector just fine when I press the arrow keys, but nothing happens with the turn speed. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the relevant code:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float turnSpeed;
    public float horizontalInput;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //Move the vehicle forward
        transform.Translate(Vector3. forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed * horizontalInput);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I resolved the issue. It turns out that I forgot to set a value for the turnSpeed variable in the Inspector.

Comment: Please, provide full code of your project for analysis

Answer (score 2):

With the code you've shared it looks like `turnSpeed` is never set or updated in `Update()`. If you always want `turnSpeed` to be constant I think you need to set the `turnSpeed` in your class similarly to how you are currently setting `speed`.

```
public float turnSpeed = 1f;
```

If you want to have the turn speed update in your `Update()` call, you'll need something like this where `rateOfChange` is how quickly you want the turning to respond

```
turnSpeed = turnSpeed * horizontalInput * rateOfChange
```